# New geometry from area

Tags: geometry, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 and I'm trying to create a geometry. I have a starting point (X,Y) and I need the geometry to be a rectangle of area = 10.000

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the rectangle to be a square buffer an extent around the starting point by half the side of your rectangle

```
ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(ol.extent.buffer([x, y, x, y], Math.sqrt(area)/2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Great solution